# Add Number for Every X line

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2008

I've a stupid issue but I can't solve it.

I need to add number beside every x records as the following:

1    123123   material1

1    123543   material2

2    123332   material3

2    123432   material4

as you see the first column is a number for every two rows..

I need to do something like that in Formula

Thanks

Comment: First column is a number and which is changing for every 2 rows... you need how to increment a number for every 2 rows?

Comment: yes this what i need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the process.

Create a formula `@counter` and place it starting of the detail.

```
Shared Numbervar counter;

counter:=counter+1;
counter
```

Create another formula `@display` and palce after counter and all other fields after that.

```
shared numbervar counter;
Shared numbervar display;

    if counter mod 2=0
    then display:=display+1;
    display
```

Comment: first part (with `counter`) works perfectly for me :) T.Hanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this using a running total in crystal reports.

- Select a field to count
- Set the summary to count
- Evaluate every record
- Reset never

This way you can have your own row count.

Hope this helps!